# Socks4 proxy support in QNetworkProxy

Tags: c++, qt, proxy, socks, qtnetwork

I am working on an application that make use of QNetworkProxy.
I want to know is, how can I include support for Socks4 type proxy in my application, as Qt only supports NoProxy, DefaultProxy, Socks5Proxy, HttpProxy, HttpCachingProxy and FtpCachingProxy.
I have already added support for NoProxy, DefaultProxy, Socks5Proxy and HttpProxy using Qt but don't know how to include Socks4proxy support. So can anyone help me in adding Socks4proxy support in my application using only Qt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "using only Qt"? As you have found out, Qt (currently) does not support Socks4.

Comment: Ok, So is there any way I can support Socks4?

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation a while ago and had no luck finding anything. There is a project implementing a [Socks4 Server](https://github.com/raptorswing/Qt-Socks-Server), but that wasn't helpful in my case.

While [looking at the Qt source](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/trees/4.8/src/network/socket) I decided that implementing a Socks4 proxy is far from being trivial. In the end, I decided to install an internal Socks5 Proxy which itself makes use of another proxy.